# Solving a System of Linear Equations Using Pseudoinverse

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, pseudoinverse

From what I know, Moore-Penrose Pseudoinverse is a method to solve overdetermined system of equations. Let $\mathbb{A}$ denote Pseudoinverse of $A$. I have the following matrices and I need to solve $Ax = b$, to do so I compute $x$ as $\mathbb{A}b$.

```
A =[
 4     2
-9    -3
 2     2
36     6]
```

and

```
b=[
 -53.5461
 -44.9373
 -51.7330
 -125.2530
 ]
```

the command `x=pinv(A)*b` in Matlab generates

```
x =
 -2.5988
 -3.1051
```

while `Ax` equals

```
-16.6054
 32.7045
-11.4079
-112.1873
```

and it is supposed to be close to `b`, but it is not at all. I would like to know  what is wrong here. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The values are correct.

Note that the system is overdetermined, which means there is no solution, and `A*(pinv(A)*b)` is giving you the projection of $b$ on the subspace generated by the columns of $A$ ($AA^+$ is the matrix of the [orthogonal projection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projection_(linear_algebra)#Orthogonal_projections) on the linear span of the columns of $A$). There is no reason it should be close to $b$.

Another way to see this: $x$ is exactly the vector of coefficients in the linear regression where the dependent variable is $b$ and the regressors are the columns of $A$. The difference between $Ax$ and $b$ is the vector of residuals.